# pandas 'line' plot not displaying all xticks

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to plot a Dataframe in `tkinter` `canvas`. The plot looks good when I use the `kind` as **bar**. But when I change it to **line**, the xticks are not fully visible.

I hope the below screenshot would be helpful.

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiPnl.png)

This is the code that I use:

```
self.fig = Figure(figsize=(8, 4.6), dpi=100)
self.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.93, bottom=0.19, right=0.97, left=0.17)
#self.fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=30)
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=400,y=240)
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().config(relief=tk.RAISED)
self.toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(master=self, height=20)
self.toolbar_frame.place(x=700,y=700)
self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self.toolbar_frame)
self.toolbar.update()
for button in self.toolbar.winfo_children():
    button.config(background='#464646')
self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
self.df.plot(x=self.labels[buttonID].cget('text'), ax=self.ax, kind="line")
self.ax.set_xticks(range(len(self.labels[buttonID].cget('text'))))
plt.setp(self.ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True, rotation=30, ha='right')
self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Just use matplotlib for plotting to circumvent this pandas bug

Comment: Yupp, seems like a bug [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22334)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of default pandas plot**

```
self.df.plot(x=self.labels[buttonID].cget('text'), ax=self.ax, kind="line")
self.ax.set_xticks(range(len(self.labels[buttonID].cget('text'))))
```

**Use Matplotlib Pyplot:**

```
self.ax.plot(self.df[self.labels[self.buttonIDcopy].cget('text')], self.df['Value'])
```